# Merge two columns of two different DataTable

Tags: c#, datatable

I have two datatable. First table have the column "ElementName,Effects,Causes" and second table have same column "ElementName,Effects,Causes". Second table have more number of elements. I need to merge additional records of ElementName column of Second table to Element Name column of First table. How can i achieve it?

For Eg

First Table

```
ElementName Effects Causes

Elm1         Eff1   caus1

Elm2         Eff2   caus2

Elm3         Eff3   caus3

Elm4         Eff4   caus4
```

Second Table

```
ElementName Effects Causes

Elm1         Eff1   caus1

Elm2         Eff2   caus2

Elm3         Eff3   caus3

Elm4         Eff4   caus4

Elm5         Eff5   caus5

Elm6         Eff6   caus6

Elm7         Eff7   caus7
```

My Expectation Result

```
ElementName Effects Causes

Elm1         Eff1   caus1

Elm2         Eff2   caus2

Elm3         Eff3   caus3

Elm4         Eff4   caus4

Elm5 

Elm6 

Elm7
```

Comment: It helps if you show code of what you have tried...

Comment: Unlike forum sites, we don't use "Thanks", or "Any help appreciated", or signatures on [so]. See "[Should 'Hi', 'thanks,' taglines, and salutations be removed from posts?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2950/should-hi-thanks-taglines-and-salutations-be-removed-from-posts).

Answer (score 0):

This is Command to Merge datatable Manually remove duplicate values and you merge

dt1.Merge(dt2);

Comment: thanks for your suggestion. But the problem was, if i use Merge function, completely second table was merged with first table. In some cases second table has same ElementName but different Effects and Causes, so ElementName get duplicated. So i want to merge  ElementName column only of two table. Any idea on this?

Comment: ya, first remove duplicates in any one datatable and then you merge

Answer (score 0):

There is a function for this method which can be clearly understood by reading the link below:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.datatable.merge(v=vs.110).aspx

Answer (score 0):

if i understood your problem correctly you can use`UNION`

try below query

```
SELECT ElementName,Effects,Causes FROM TABLE1
UNION
SELECT ElementName,Effects,Causes FROM TABLE2
```